# Phpword and accented characters

Tags: diacritics, non-ascii-characters, phpword

Hi I have a problem with php word. When I use accented characters in my file, the file is corrupted and impossible to open.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Documents/LM.docx');
$document->setValue('Value1', "example with accent évian");
$document->save('Documents/LMD.docx');

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your code generates a word file that is not corrupted when used without the special accented characters. But in any case, could you try with the below version? The loadTemplate function is deprecated in the 0.13.0 version and TemplateProcessor should be used instead + htmlspecialchars wrapping should be generally used for text contents.

```
$templateProcessor = new PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('Documents/LM.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue('Value1', htmlspecialchars('example with accent évian', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
$templateProcessor->saveAs('Documents/LMD.docx');
```

This is working for me with no issues with PhpWord 0.13.0